# Using substring in SQL update statement - oracle

Tags: oracle, set, substr

I'm writing a SQL query that updates just only one field of a string (tax_cd) but it doesn't work,
I must replace field 12 which is '0' or blank with '1',character 0 is the one you found in the condition where, all other characters in the string should not be changed

TAX_CD is a VARCHAR2(26)

```
UPDATE doc_table
SET tax_cd=substr(tax_cd,1,11)||'1'||substr(tax_cd,13,26)
WHERE substr(tax_cd,12,1) = 0 ;
```

Current : "ABC 0      0      L K     "

Updated : "ABC 0      1      L K     "

any advice?

the string is not
always equal as length, for example:

it is written on the table like this

"0 K 1"

so the ideal is to read the record field with a select, make a length
and based on that try to write in position 12 the code 1 but I do not
know how to do it

Lenght(tax_cd) Count(*)

- 2 3
- 3 376
- 4 32
- 5 22
- 6 16
- 7 1
- 8 2
- 25 6
- null 6

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like

```
SQL> with test (tax_cd) as
  2    (select 'ABC 0      0      L K     ' from dual union all
  3     select 'DEF 0             L K     ' from dual union all
  4     select 'XYZ 7      2      F M     ' from dual
  5    )
  6  select tax_cd,
  7    case when substr(tax_cd, 12, 1) in ('0', ' ') then
  8              substr(tax_cd, 1, 11) || '1' || substr(tax_cd, 13)
  9         else tax_cd
 10    end as new_value
 11  from test;

TAX_CD                     NEW_VALUE
-------------------------- ------------------------------
ABC 0      0      L K      ABC 0      1      L K
DEF 0             L K      DEF 0      1      L K
XYZ 7      2      F M      XYZ 7      2      F M

SQL>
```

so you'd

```
update doc_table set
  tax_cd = substr(tax_cd, 1, 11) || '1' || substr(tax_cd, 13)
  where substr(tax_cd, 12, 1) in ('0', ' ');
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, because the string is not
always equal as length

Comment: Well, that's quite the **opposite** from what you initially said: "I must replace field 12 which is '0' or blank ...". If string length is from 2 to 25 (according to what you recently posted), how do you plan to modify position 12 in a string that is only 3 characters long? Perhaps you should edit (again) the initial question and post some more sample data. Please, use [CODE] tags to preserve formatting!